# How to integrate Facebook like button to jsf?

Tags: javascript, xml, facebook, jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to integrate a Facebook like button to my JSF side but it doesn't work. Where is the problem? I get the following:
Eclipse says, data-href etc is a undefined tag.

Here is my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <body>


        <ui:composition>

            <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" 
data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" 
data-layout="standard" 
data-action="like" 
data-show-faces="true" 
data-share="true"></div>

 <div id="footer">


 </div>

        </ui:composition>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope you can help me.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried specifying HTML5 instead of XHTML? Replace your `DOCTYPE` with `<!DOCTYPE html>` to try.

Comment: Paul's idea is a good one, but are you sure that error message is correct? Does the page still work? Do any errors appear in the console or browser developer tools when you click the button? Sometimes IDEs issue syntax errors where none exist.

Comment: No, the page doesn't work any more. I get the error: javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /footer2.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 1] Verarbeitungsanweisungsziel, das "[xX][mM][lL]" entspricht, ist nicht zulässig.
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:456)
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:430)

Comment: My German (?) is rusty. What does that say? (FYI, people will not receive comment notifications if you don't @ mention them or reply to an Answer they posted.)

Comment: In the script part,replace the & with &amp;

Comment: Wrap any JS code inside a `CDATA` tag or place any JS code in own JS file(s).